# Trigger with a Variable Select and Order by

Tags: sql-server, trigger, table

Is there a way to a set trigger that will activate once a new table is created and will get the new tables name?
I was able to come up with the query below but it only gets the first query by alphabetical order, not by date created

```
CREATE TRIGGER CreateTable
ON DATABASE
    FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
     DECLARE
       @table varchar(max);
     SELECT  top 1  @table =   [name] FROM sys.tables 
     insert into NewTable values(@table)
     ;
     end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't look at `sys.tables` for that... even if you got the last one created, on a busy system, how would you know that someone else didn't create one more recently? With `TOP` comes `ORDER BY` so the following would likely work most of the time, but it is a completely bad idea:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @table = name FROM sys.tables ORDER BY create_date DESC;
```

No, instead, you need to extract the table name from `EVENTDATA()`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CreateTable
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
      @sql       nvarchar(MAX),
      @EventData xml = EVENTDATA();

    ;WITH x(s,o) 
    AS
    (
      SELECT
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',  'nvarchar(128)'), 
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'nvarchar(128)')
    )
    INSERT dbo.NewTable(ColumnName)
      SELECT QUOTENAME(s) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(o)
      FROM x;
END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH C
AS
(
SELECT 
     [name], object_id, create_date, modify_date
FROM
     A.sys.tables ),
     D
     AS
         (
     SELECT * FROM A.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     )
     SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
     FROM C
     INNER JOIN D
     ON C.NAME =D.TABLE_NAME
     ORDER BY create_date DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
     FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

A = your database name